# How should I name Apache Camel DSL elements? Are they "functions"? "Methods"? "Verbs"?

Tags: java, apache-camel, naming-conventions, dsl

When I want to refer to the elements used in creating a [route in Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/manual/routes.html) (like `from`, `setBody`, `to`, etc), what name should I use? Just call it a "function"? Can I call "method"? Or does it have a more specific and appropriate name?

I've seen people calling it "verb". Would that be an appropriate nomination too?

An example of route definition is:

```java
from("rest:post:bin")
.removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI)
.setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
.to("http://httpbin.org/anything")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
.setBody(simple("${body[data]}"))
```

In this example we use the `from`, `removeHeader`, `setHeader`, `to`, `unmarshal` and `setBody` elements of the Java DSL.

I know that, programmatically, they are function and methods. But using code is not the only way to define a route. We can use these same elements to define a route using the [XML or Yaml DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/dsl.html), for example. So I imagine that simply calling "function" might not be the most appropriate option for naming these DSL elements.

Thanks!

Comment: For me, the question is unclear. Can you [edit] the post and give some examples of the different cases?

Comment: @Turing85, Okay, I just did it

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should use terms defined in the Enterprise integration patterns book and [website](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/). This is what Camel documentation uses, what Camel in Action book uses and what are generally considered to be most universal terms when using camel whether you use xml-dsl, yaml-dsl or Java-dsl.

Camel Java-DSL uses something like [Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that uses [method-chaining technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) to define routes.

In Java-DSL when you call `from("direct:example")` method in your route-builder Camel creates new RouteDefition with `direct:example` Consumer-endpoint. The Method returns you the `RouteDefinition` object which you can then use to add Producer-endpoints and processors to that `RouteDefinition` generally using a [pipeline](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pipeline-eip.html).

**Examples:**

- from() -> Consumer endpoint
- to() -> Producer endpoint / Enricher
- removeHeader, setHeader, unmarshal and setBody -> Processors
- split() -> Spillter
- aggregate() -> Aggregator